# lock browser to troubleshoot javascript and css

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, troubleshooting, javascript

Let's say I created some tooltip which displays a popup when the cursor is placed over a given part of the page, and removes it when I move the mouse.  For an example, see http://jsbin.com/aCoboQo/1 and try to put your mouse over the popup.

I now wish to troubleshoot it and need to check the CSS using Firebug or some other similar tool.

I currently deal do this by editing the JavaScript and comment out the un-hoover.

It would be nice to somehow lock the browser after the popup is shown, so then I could navigate to the popup (and not have the popup disappear) and inspect the HTML and CSS.

Is this possible with any standard browser (ie, chrome, firefox/firebug, etc)?  If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have Firefox:

1. select an object
2. right-click, choose `Inspect element` from dropdown menu
3. once "inspecting", expand another dropdown menu (as seen on the attached screen)
4. you may now select and hold desired state (ie. `:hover`)

The browser will hold it till refresh.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Only works for CSS but not for JavaScript-based hover effects.

Comment: It's hard to help when I don't see the code, though two advices:

Comment: (a) try to controll popup via CSS. You can ie. create `<span classs="TextWithTooltip">Text with hoover effect<span>Tooltip Text</span></span>`, then control appearance of sub-span (`.TextWithTooltip:hover>span { display: block; position: relative; }`)

Comment: Thanks Michal,  How did you open the dropdown you show with `:hover`, etc?

Comment: (b) you may alternatively control the visibility of the tooltip via class assignment, for the sake of simplicity `.invisible` might do the job; then via disabling `display:none` in that class you would immediately see all the tooltips.

Comment: I have opened it as explained above, by right-clicking the object and following steps I described. Use the arrow on the right side of black tooltip.

Comment: My whole reason for asking this question is to view the resulting html/css without taking the time to edit the script.

Comment: @user1032531: Once again, if you control the appearance of the tooltip via JavaScript, not via `:hoover`, you will need to change your script using method (a) or (b). Once that is done, you will be forever able to display and hide tooltips without messing up with script again.

Comment: Ah, I see I need to inspect using Q and not Firebug, correct?  I now see your dropdown.  Doesn't seem to bring up the popup but I will continue to experiment.

Comment: You may also write a javascript bookmarklet to globally show your tooltips.

Comment: For instance, without editing the JS or CSS, how would you view the CSS applied to or the class names added to the new `<DIV>` created when hoover over john, jane, or baby doe shown on http://jsbin.com/aCoboQo/1/.  .